# How to display next object from table after upvote without reloading page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm still very new to programming, so I'm not really sure what I'm looking for, and I'm using Ruby on Rails.

**What I want to do:**

I have a root_path that I want to display a single post from my posts table. And then, when the user clicks the upvote or downvote button, I want to display the next image from my table (maybe as a randomized queue) without loading the page again.

I would want users to be able to vote through the entire posts table that way, seeing one post at a time.

Is there something in Rails that allows me to do what I want?

Comment: Do you want a set number of posts on the page or do you want the whole list to update every click?

Comment: @user1943992 Well, I only want one post display at a time. Are you asking if I'd want something like 14 posts in a queue (15 total, with 1 displaying and 14 in queue)? So you would see one post, vote, then the next post in queue would show up, and there would be 13 posts left in queue. If you got to the end of the queue, the page could refresh with a new set of 15

Comment: I was going to suggest you use an AJAX request, which you still can if you'd like but trh's answer will get the job done. There are pluses and minuses to each approach but I think trh's answer is simpler overall. If you want me to explain an AJAX request approach let me know.

Comment: @user1943992 Yes, please, I would be very much interested in hearing the AJAX approach as well. Also, if you know of any resources that introduce AJAX within the context of rails, please let me know.

Comment: Using AJAX and JSON for this, as was my original thought would be a bad approach here. However AJAX and JSON can come in handy. [Here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) is the api for working with AJAX in javascript. [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) is the rails guide to working with AJAX in rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, the easiest way to accomplish your goals is to:

- **view**: create the 'random' partial that can be rendered from within your view, or from js
- **view**: use an id div to wrap around your post so it can easily be replaced later
- **view**: in your link to upvote or downvote use `remote: true` so your request is processed as javascript
- **routes**: add a route for `upvote` and `downvote` that correspond to your controller action (which controller will depend on whether voting is bundled into the post model or if its separate)
- **controller**: make you have a proper respond_to block that will handle hte javascript request (or respond_with depending on your preference)
- **view**: create a view for the "next_post" as javascript, e.g. `next_post.js.erb` or `next_post.js.haml`
- **view**: in your next post js view, render the partial for the next post to replace the existing one, such as `$('#random-post').replaceWith("<%= j render(:partial => 'posts/random', :locals => {:post => @post}) %>");`

That's it in the broadest terms.  Give it a go and try it yourself, if you get stuck just come back and post a specific question with your code example.  Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. After reading your answer, it looks like what I'm trying to do will require some knowledge of JavaScript, yes?

Comment: Not really, just the single line will replace an html div called #random-post with the contents of a new one..  BUT I've edited my answer to make sure you're passing the new partial the new post object.  It's rails magic that does the rest.